# huawei api sms documentation

Tags: api, sms

any one have the huawei SMS API documentation? (api/sms/sms-list)

I need to know how to talk with this API to get the SMS list:

It must be something like this:

```
<request>
<PageIndex>1</PageIndex>
<ReadCount>20</ReadCount>
<BoxType>1</BoxType>
<SortType>0</SortType>
<Ascending>0</Ascending>
<UnreadPreferred>0</UnreadPreferred>
</request>
```

But I got only a error code 100003 as answer. And I don't what that mean.

Thank You,
michel

Comment: I was unable to find any documentation, but this error code happens when you have not logged in or `__RequestVerificationToken` is not set correctly to the current token (changes too often) in the request header. You cannot directly call `api/sms/sms-list`. You need to obtain current token from `/api/webserver/token`, login using `/api/user/login`.

Comment: thank you for your question helped me a lot

Answer (score 2):

I have done this on an Huawei E5221 with Python. The error you are getting is because you are not authenticated and need to login first. Then the list can be retrieved.

Also note that all API requests are POST's and not GET's.

Method to login:

```
def LoginToSMSGateway(sms_gateway_ip, username, password):
api_url = '/api/user/login'
post_data = '<request><Username>'+username+'</Username><Password>'+ base64.b64encode(password) +'</Password>'

r = requests.post(url='http://' + sms_gateway_ip + api_url, data=post_data)
if r.status_code == 200:
    result = False
    root = ET.fromstring(r.text)

    for results in root.iter('response'):
        if results.text == 'OK':
            result = True

    return result
else:
    return False
```

Method to retrieve SMS List (The method will turn the XML results into a Python list of SMS's):

```
def GetSMSList(sms_gateway_ip):
class SMS:
    Opened = False
    Message = ''


api_url = '/api/sms/sms-list'
post_data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><PageIndex>1</PageIndex><ReadCount>20</ReadCount><BoxType>1</BoxType><SortType>0</SortType><Ascending>0</Ascending><UnreadPreferred>0</UnreadPreferred></request>'

headers = {'Referer': 'http://' + sms_gateway_ip + '/html/smsinbox.html'}

r = requests.post(url='http://' + sms_gateway_ip + api_url, data=post_data, headers=headers)

root = ET.fromstring(r.text)

resultsList = list()
for messages in root.iter('Messages'):
    for message in messages:
        sms = SMS()
        sms.Message = message.find('Content').text
        sms.Opened = False if message.find('SmsType').text == '1' else True
        resultsList.append(sms)

return resultsList
```

To use it(The IP and credentials are the default values and need to be secured.) :

```
if LoginToSMSGateway('192.168.1.1', 'admin', 'admin'):
print 'Logged in.'

smsList = GetSMSList('192.168.1.1')
for sms in smsList:
    print sms.Message
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this the subject has been posted I think the API has changed a bit.

To get the SMS list, no need to login but you do need to get a sessionID and the corresponding Token. You can use that Method to get them.

```
def GetTokenAndSessionID(sms_gateway_ip):
    url = '/html/smsinbox.html'
    r = requests.get(sms_gateway_ip + url)
    Setcookie = r.headers.get('set-cookie')
    sessionID = Setcookie.split(';')[0]
    token =  re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', r.text)[2]
    return token, sessionID
```

And then the Method to get the sms list (It's using the first Method to wrap the sessionID and the Token in the headers).

```
def GetSmsList(sms_gateway_ip):
    class SMS:
        Opened = False
        Message = ''

    url = '/api/sms/sms-list'
    token,sessionID = GetTokenAndSessionID(sms_gateway_ip)
    post_data = '<request><PageIndex>1</PageIndex><ReadCount>20</ReadCount><BoxType>2</BoxType><SortType>0</SortType><Ascending>0</Ascending><UnreadPreferred>0</UnreadPreferred></request>'
    headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                '__RequestVerificationToken': token,
                'Cookie': sessionID
              }
    r = requests.post(sms_gateway_ip + url, data = post_data, headers=headers)

    root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
    resultsList = list()

    for messages in root.iter('Messages'):
        for message in messages :
            sms = SMS()
            sms.Message = message.find('Content').text
            sms.Opened = False if message.find('SmsType').text == '1' else True
            resultsList.append(sms)
```

To use it you just need to call it with the ip of the sms gateway: 192.168.8.1

```
GetSmsList(sms_gateway_ip)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar Code in Java hereunder using Apache HTTP Client classes

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

// 1. Have apache HTTPClient manage the cookie containing the SessionID
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
httpContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

// 2. Extract the token
String token = "";
HttpGet hget = new HttpGet("http://192.168.8.1/html/smsinbox.html");
CloseableHttpResponse getRespo = httpclient.execute(hget, httpContext);
try {
    StatusLine statusLine = getRespo.getStatusLine();
    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() >= 300) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(statusLine.getStatusCode(), statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }
    HttpEntity entity = getRespo.getEntity();
    if (entity == null) {
        throw new ClientProtocolException("Get response contains no content");
    }
    long len = entity.getContentLength();
    StringTokenizer st = null;
    if (len != -1 && len > 250) {
        st = new StringTokenizer(EntityUtils.toString(entity).substring(0, 250), "\"");
    }
    int i = 1;
    while (st != null && st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        if (i++ == 10) {
            token = st.nextToken();
            break;
        } else {
            st.nextToken();
        }
    }
} finally {
    getRespo.close();
}
System.out.println("Token: " + token);

// 3. Get the SMS messages using the Token
HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.8.1/api/sms/sms-list");

String xmlRequest = "<request><PageIndex>1</PageIndex><ReadCount>1</ReadCount><BoxType>1</BoxType><SortType>0</SortType><Ascending>0</Ascending><UnreadPreferred>1</UnreadPreferred></request>";
StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity(xmlRequest);
reqEntity.setContentType("text/xml");

hpost.setEntity(reqEntity);
hpost.addHeader("__RequestVerificationToken", token);

CloseableHttpResponse postRespo = httpclient.execute(hpost, httpContext);
try {
    StatusLine statusLine = postRespo.getStatusLine();
    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() >= 300) {
        throw new HttpResponseException(statusLine.getStatusCode(), statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }
    HttpEntity entity = postRespo.getEntity();
    if (entity == null) {
        throw new ClientProtocolException("Response contains no content");
    }
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
    //Your further processing here. 
} finally {
    postRespo.close();
}
```